# How can I retrieve data from mysql into my eventcalendar?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve data from my mysql database into a php calendar which I've downloaded from the web. The result from this code is that the page wont stop loading. I know it's somehow related to a loop. I want to highlight the date if there is an event saved with the same date.

```
db connection//
```

class Calendar {

```
public function __construct($year = '', $month = '') {

    $date = time();

    if (empty($year) OR empty($month)) {
        $year = date('Y', $date);
        $month = date('m', $date);
        $day = date('d', $date);
    }

    $first_day = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
    $title = date('F', $first_day);
    $day_of_week = date('D', $first_day);

     switch ($day_of_week) {
        case "Mon": $blank = 0;
            break;
        case "Tue": $blank = 1;
            break;
        case "Wed": $blank = 2;
            break;
        case "Thu": $blank = 3;
            break;
        case "Fri": $blank = 4;
            break;
        case "Sat": $blank = 5;
            break;
        case "Sun": $blank = 6;
            break;
    }

    $days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);

    echo '<table width="100%" class="table table-striped">';

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th colspan=60>' . $title . ' ' . $year . '</th>';
    echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td width=62>Mån</td>';
    echo '<td width=62>Tis</td>';
    echo '<td width=62>Ons</td>';
    echo '<td width=62>Tors</td>';
    echo '<td width=62>Fre</td>';
    echo '<td width=62>Lör</td>';
    echo '<td width=62>Sön</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $day_count = 1;

    while ($blank > 0) {

     echo '<td></td>';
        $blank = $blank - 1;
        $day_count++;
   }

    $day_num = 1;
    $day_today = date('Y-m-d');
     while ($day_num <= $days_in_month) {

                    $sql = "SELECT id, event_name, event_date FROM events WHERE event_date = '".$day_today."'";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);

                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                       if(date('d') == $event_date) {
                                           echo "<td> <u>$day_num</u> </td>";
                                           $day_num++;
                                           $day_count++;
                                        }

                        }
                    } else {

                           if(date('d') != $day_num) {
           echo "<td> $day_num </td>";
           $day_num++;
           $day_count++;
       } 
       if(date('d') == $day_num) {
           echo "<td> <strong>$day_num</strong> </td>";
           $day_num++;
           $day_count++;
       }            
        if ($day_count > 7) {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
            $day_count = 1;
        }

    }

                    }

    while ($day_count > 1 && $day_count <= 7) {
        echo '<td> </td>';
        $day_count++;
    }

    echo '</tr>';

    echo '</table>';
}
```

}

$c = new Calendar($year, $month);

Answer (score 0):

There is no increase of `$day_num` if the condition in your loop does not apply (and that's the case because `$event_date` does not exists) and the script will run infinitely.

```
if (date('d') == $row["event_date"]) // instead of $event_date
```

On the other hand, this loop and this conditon seems unnecessary to me. If you only want to mark the day, a check on `$result->num_rows` should be enough.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    echo "<td> <u>$day_num</u> </td>";
    $day_num ++;
    $day_count ++;
}
```

Regarding to your database query, you currently request always data for the same day, because `$day_today` is always the current day. You could try something like this instead:

```
    $check_date = $year ."-". $month ."-". $day_num;

    $sql = "SELECT id, event_name, event_date FROM events 
    WHERE event_date = '" .$check_date . "'";
```

I hope this helps you further.